# What is the significance of compileSdkVersion in selecting implementations and resources?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version, android-components

I am asking this to confirm my understanding about the use of compileSdkVersion in android.

Android sdk provides the implementation for each version under the path (Your sdk root)/Sdk/platforms/android-(sdk version) .So if you set the compileSdkVersion to say 20 and if you add a class extending Activity in your code , after building apk the apk will be packaged using Activity.class implementation taken from (Your sdk root)/Sdk/platforms/android-20/andriod.jar.

So suppose google adds a method say 'public void f1()' in the Activity implementation in android-22/android.jar and I compile my code with compileSdkVersion 22 and I am calling the method f1() from my code and I am going to run the app in a device with android version 20.

Question 1 : If the method f1() is a java layer method and not something which calls C/C++ implementations , will it run properly in the device?

When I opened the View.class file in my android studio with compileSdkVersion set as 23, I could see in the import list an item 'android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable'.But when I went inside (Your sdk root)/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar I could never find the class 'ScrollBarDrawable' inside widget folder(and I came across many such implementations which are not present in android sdk like this)

Question 2 : So when apk is packaged from where does the apk builder get the implementation android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.class?

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after building apk the apk will be packaged using Activity.class implementation taken from (Your sdk root)/Sdk/platforms/android-20/andriod.jar

I would phrase it as: your subclass of `Activity` will be compiled against the `Activity.class` in that JAR file. Nothing from that JAR is packaged with your APK, with the exception of `final static int` values and the like that are inlined into the bytecode.

> If the method f1() is a java layer method and not something which calls C/C++ implementations , will it run properly in the device?

No, if that method does not exist on the older device.

> So when apk is packaged from where does the apk builder get the implementation android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.class?

The "apk builder" neither knows nor cares about such a class, as that class is not in the Android SDK.

On the device, a *different* JAR is part of your app's classpath, that contains the actual implementations of `Activity` and so forth. Whether that JAR contains a hidden `android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable` will vary by OS release, presumably.

Comment: Thank u very much..a real eye opener for me